# How to safely remove the footer (twentytwenty)

Tags: php, footer

Is it safe to remove

```
get_footer();
```

from the index.php ?

I don't need any footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not safe and not recommended. Thats action that read all Javascripts, CSS from other plugins or theme.

Hide your footer with css or theme option.

```css
#footer,footer{display:none!important}
```

Comment: Ok. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be safe if you replace it with [`wp_footer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/), which is the function that includes enqueued scripts in the page and other footer actions in the page. (and maybe optionally `do_action( 'get_footer', null, array() );` first, in case you have anything that hooks that.)

But IMO the best / clearest thing to do would be to override footer.php in a child theme with a version that was just

```php
<?php wp_footer();
```

and leave index.php calling get_footer() as usual.

However there's still a risk that any of the theme scripts you have loaded assume the footer element always exists and try to access it. So please check you don't have any script errors afterwards. If you do, you'd either have to fix the script or leave the footer on the page and use the display:none from the other answer.